# Форма с датой рождения Html

Tags: html, python, django

Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь вводил дату, появлялись слеши, то есть: он вводит '23072000', а появляется 23/07/2004? Это мне нужно, чтобы дата всегда была валидна

шаблон

```
        <form>
            <p>
                <label for="localdate">Дата рождения: </label>
                {{ form.date_of_birht }}
            </p>
           
        </form>
```

часть формы

```
"date_of_birht" : TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 45px; border-radius: 4px;" name="date',
                'id': 'localdate',
                'placeholder': 'День Месяц Год Пример: 12 мая 2012'
                }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"date_of_birht" : TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 45px; border-radius: 4px;" name="date',
                'id': 'localdate',
                'placeholder': 'День Месяц Год Пример: 12/05/2012',
                'pattern': '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'
                }),
```

Подробнее [читай тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/pattern)